# soffice how to get information error

Tags: perl, error-handling, libreoffice

I'm trying to convert docx and xlsx files to pdf.
I have cgi perl script on server it worked fine but now it doesnt.
I didnt do any change.
When I try:

```
system("export HOME=/tmp && soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir pdf/LgfpQJtC 'pdf/LgfpQJtC/example.docx'");
print"$?";
```

I get:

```
19712
```

The file example exist and it's in right directory.
But pdf file wont create. 
When I run the same command as root in command line it works fine.
I tried set full acces to directory and file but it didnt help.

Is there any way to get more information about error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can execute it fine as root, but not in the script, it sounds like a permission issue. Does the  user executing the script  have write permissions in the target directory and does that directory exist or is it created ? Also, note that outdir is simply "pdf/" which will attempt to write into pdf directory from where the script currently is, I would try setting a full path there, unless soffice somehow knows better.

Comment: User has the permissions to write into directory and directory already exist. I try set the full path but it doesnt help.